# Как прописать кнопки в телеграм боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Хочу чтобы при на нажатии на кнопку 'oper1', людей перебрасывало на контакт пользователя телеграмм, но не знаю как реализовать

```
elif call.data == "oper":
    next_menu2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    oper1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Оператор", user='@OP')
    back = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад', callback_data='mainmenu')
    next_menu2.add(oper1, back)
    bot.edit_message_text('Выберите кнопку', call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id,
                          reply_markup=next_menu2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
oper1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Оператор', url='https://t.me/username')
```